# Upload Media Item to Media Library Folder Through HTTP Request via ItemWebAPI

Tags: media-library, item-web-api

I am using the ItemWebAPI and attempting to create a media item in a subfolder of my Media Library. The documentation I am referencing for this is here: https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-usletter.pdf

Under the section "Creating Media Items" the documentation suggests that the only parameter required is `name`. My questions are:

1) Where and how do you define the media to be uploaded (`example.jpeg`) in the HTTP request?

2) Is it possible to point Sitecore to a public url of the image to handle the upload (`https://www.public_url.com/for/example.jpeg`)? Example of request?

For additional context, the current URL built for this request is:

`POST: https://<sitecore_host>/-/item/v1/sitecore/media library/Images?sc_itemid={id_of_destination_subfolder}&name={media_item_name}`

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Alex! Can you mention the Sitecore version that you're using?

Comment: Did you check the sample code in this link - https://sitecoreinsight.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/how-to-create-media-items-using-sitecore-item-web-api/ ?

Comment: @Paulson this should be version independent. I appreciate that link and it was helpful for the direct upload. Do you have insight on question 2? Uploading an image via a public url.

Comment: Do you mean uploading an image (which is available in a public URL) to the Media Library? Then the link I shared above is an example of this only. The code handles uploading an image available in this public URL http://www.logotypes101.com/free_vector_logo_png/101376/4109B58D03089AE3D610E87E14474CE6/Sitecore.png.